# Problem in ubuntu 18.04 interface - Congested

Tags: upgrade

[image]
I recently upgraded ubuntu 16.04 LTS to ubuntu 18.04 LTS and get an issue with its interface on opening Files(also on clicking left click) everything is so congested
(Take a look at the screenshot).

How to fix it?

Comment: Do you want icons and text larger? What is your monitor resolution?

Comment: I want the left column that contain (Recent, Home, Desktop, Documents,...............,+Other Locations) in the ubuntu style. and my laptop resolution is 1366x768 pixels (361x203 millimeters).

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix On right click i get option in very unusal way (Take a look at the screenshot).     https://i.stack.imgur.com/eoMb2.jpg

Comment: It looks like you previously installed your own GTK theme. Try uninstalling it or selecting a new one with the Tweaks program (you may need to install it with `apt install gnome-tweak-tool`).